# Asked about inference between repositories in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

i want to separate data on different repository such as person repo, document repo for saving large dataset and also different datasources. I know that the fedarated query can query over multiple repo, but i want to infer the facts between those repo. Is there any way that i can do that and connect more effciently between two repo?

I read about the nested repo. But i don't understand about the inference and saving data. Importantly, its disable feature owl:sameAs which i need. Can anyone explain it more clearly ?

Is there a way that multiple repositories uses only one ontology ? It means when updating ontology, those repo updated as well.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Afraid that this is not possible with GraphDB. The inference engine works over the data stored in single repository so you could not derive additional data across multiple repositories.

Comment: About ontology updates: you'll have to reload the ontology in all repos that use it. The easiest is to put it in a graph, and use SPARQL Graph Protocol to replace at once. Of course, that means re-inference of all data inferred from the ontology